# Code throws SQLException but SQL code execute successful

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sqlexception

I am trying to insert data into a MySQL database, but Java throws an `SQLException` signalling syntax error. But when I execute the exact same SQL code (copied, pasted) on MySQL Console, it executes successfully. I would like to ask what is causing the weird behaviour and how to resolve it.

Java code:

```
    sql = "INSERT INTO record_t "
        + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
    prepSql = this.conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    prepSql.setString(1, id);
    prepSql.setString(2, roomNum);
    prepSql.setString(3, name);
    prepSql.setString(4, ic);
    prepSql.setString(5, tel);
    prepSql.setString(6, email);
    prepSql.setString(7, checkIn);
    prepSql.setString(8, checkOut);
    prepSql.setBoolean(9, false);
    
    System.out.println(prepSql);
    
    rowInserted = prepSql.executeUpdate(sql);
    if (rowInserted > 0) {
        System.out.println("success");
    }
```

Java return message:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: INSERT INTO record_t VALUES ('RCD00003', 'GF3', 'asfd', 'asfd', 'asdfasdf', 'asdf', '2021-10-25', '2021-10-26', 0);
Error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Error State: 42000
```

SQL Code:

```
INSERT INTO record_t VALUES ('RCD00003', 'GF3', 'asfd', 'asfd', 'asdfasdf', 'asdf', '2021-10-25', '2021-10-26', 0);
```

MySQL return message:

```
[1:1] Executed successfully in 0 s.
1 row affected.
Execution finished after 0.002 s, no errors occurred.
```

Comment: Remove the semicolumn...

Comment: remove the trailing semicolon `;` from your `insert` statement. `...?);"` should be `...?)"`